# AJAX proceed before the command end

Tags: php, html, ajax, batch-file

I have a php file,as interface and contain 3 button to press. 1st and 2nd button will directed to a download link that generate by a scheduler batch file. While the run.php will be call when 3rd button is click, then it will manually execute the batch file to get latest updated of the file.

Problem: When i tried in localhost, the div "statusNow" will only change from " please wait, in the progress" to " completed " when the scheduler.bat file is fully run.

but when i put the file in life server, before the batch file is fully run(basically after the first xcopy command), its change the status to completed already.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function dothework()
{
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("statusNow").innerHTML="Completed";
    document.getElementById("b1").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("b2").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("b3").disabled=false;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","run.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
document.getElementById("b1").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("b2").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("b3").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("statusNow").innerHTML="Please wait... In the progess...";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<button type="button" id="b1" onclick="window.location.href='downloadlink1'"</button>
<button type="button" id="b2" onclick="window.location.href='downloadlink2'"</button>
<br><br>

<button type="button" id="b3" onclick="dothework()">Export</button>
<div id="statusNow"><h2></h2></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

here will be the php file

```
<?php
system("cmd /c C:\scheduler.bat");
?>
```

the scheduler file

```
@echo off

xcopy C:afile C:download\afile /s /e /i /y

cd C:download\
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -df -r "afile.rar" "afile"

xcopy C:bfile C:download\bfile /s /e /i /y

cd C:download\
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -df -r "bfile.rar" "bfile"
```

Comment: in local, the batch treatment is almost instant, right?

Comment: It is around 1-2 minutes for it to finish. I keep refreshing on the folder to follow up the process, from folder, den to zip, then another folder, then zip again. Then in the end the "Completed" just show after the two zip file completed.